# Google Analytics API v3 unknown error. createEventWithCategory: not compiling

Tags: google-analytics

GAIDictionaryBuilder set forKey:GAISessionControl error reads: key for value says it's not code compliant.

```
GAIDictionaryBuilder *dictionary = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UX" action:@"App started" label:nil value:nil];
[dictionary setValue:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:dictionary.build];
```

I am following Google's documentation directly from their site, & still have no idea where the error is coming from? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration#setting-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics documentation has an error (like usual). I got rid of the error by replacing "setValue:" with "set:"

from:
    [dictionary setValue:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl];

to:
    [dictionary set:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl];

Works perfectly now.

```
GAIDictionaryBuilder *dictionary = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UX" action:@"App started" label:nil value:nil];
[dictionary setValue:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:dictionary.build];
```